# Is it possible to sort a bootstrapped array in `O(n)` knowing the original array's order

Tags: algorithm, sorting, decision-tree

## Summary:

I have an array `x` of length `n` and can run all kinds of `O(nlog(n))` operations on `x` and cache results. E.g. I can pre-compute `indices = argsort(x)` and `order = argsort(argsort(x))`. Now, given `sample`, which is an array of indices `0` to `n` of length at most `n`, I would like to compute `argsort(x[sample])` in `O(length(sample))` time (or as fast as possible). Is this possible?

## Background:

To train a decision tree on a dataset `(X, y)`, at each split we are given an array with indices corresponding to obervations at the node (`sample`), and need to compute `y[argsort(X[sample, i])]` for each feature `i` in my dataset. A random forest is an ensemble of decision trees trained on `X[sample, :]` where `sample` is a length `n` array of indices . I am wondering if it is possible to only sort each feature once (i.e. pre-compute `argsort(X[:, i])` for each `i`) and reuse this in every tree.

One can assume that `sample` is sorted.

## Example

Consider `x = [0.5, 9.5, 2.5, 8.5, 6.5, 3.5, 5.5, 4.5, 1.5, 7.5]`. Then `indices = argsort(x) = [0, 8, 2, 5, 7, 6, 4, 9, 3, 1]`. Let `sample = [9, 9, 5, 6, 4]`. we would like to obtain `argsort(x[sample]) = [2, 3, 4, 0, 1]` without any sorting / in `O(length(sample))` time.

## Ideas

Given `samples`, we can compute `counts = tabulate(samples)`. For the above example this would be equal to `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2]`. If `inverse_tabulate` is the inverse of `tabulate` (irgnoring order), then `inverse_tabulate(tabulate(samples)[indices]) = argsort(x[samples])`. However to my best understanding `inverse_tabulate` is optimally `O(n)` in time, which is suboptimal if `length(sample) << n`.

## References

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212610/why-is-the-runtime-to-construct-a-decision-tree-mnlogn) discusses the runtime of decision trees. [This lecture script](https://sebastianraschka.com/pdf/lecture-notes/stat479fs18/06_trees_notes.pdf) mentiones on page 6, paragraph 4:

> (Many implementations such as scikit-learn use efficient caching tricks to keep track of the
> general order of indices at each node such that the features do not need to be re-sorted at
> each node; hence, the time complexity of these implementations merely is O(m · n log(n)).)

This *caching* however seems to only be within one tree. Also, looking at the scikit-learn tree [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1a7cdbf0c540a1136640f3188c89d3703b616dae/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx#L492-L522), the `samples` appear to be re-sorted at each step / for each split.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is possible for worst case runtime.  But average run-time, assuming a random sample, it is.

The idea is to do a [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) sending each sample to the bucket:

```
position of sample in overall list * number of samples / n
```

Each bucket should get a number of samples described by a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with λ = 1.  So walk through the buckets in order, sort it with your favorite sorting algorithm, then add it to the list.

It is worth noting that for arrays below 20-30 elements, insertion sort tends to be the fastest.  The odds against a bucket having more elements than that are truly astronomical.  So I'd recommend using insertion sort.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand correctly a radix sort can be always be applied if I know the distribution of my values to sort. I don't expect it to be very quick in practice.

I am looking for a solution that uses the assumptions stated above, i.e. the fact that we are able to "pre-sort" before sampling.

Comment: @M.Londschien A pure radix sort can be applied if you know the distribution exactly.  The kind of radix bucketing sort that I gave will work if you know it approximately.  If it is a random sample, then thanks to your "pre-sort", we know the order approximately